# Something strange in string.compare()

Tags: c#, string

Here, i don't understand when i compare string **".doc"** with string **".exe"**, Compare method gives -1 value and false as a return. Where it have to return True and 1 value as a return just because i set it as **"==1"**.

When i compare string **".exe"** with  string **".txt"** and string  **".exe"** it's give valid return value.

Can anyone tell me what actually happened here?

```
int nDocValue = string.Compare(".doc", ".exe");          
Console.WriteLine(nDocValue);                            // Will display -1
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(".doc", ".exe") == 1);  // False

int nTxtValue = string.Compare(".txt", ".exe");          
Console.WriteLine(nTxtValue);                            // Will display 1
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(".txt", ".exe") == 1);  // True

int nExeValue = string.Compare(".exe", ".exe");          
Console.WriteLine(nExeValue);                            // Will display 0
Console.WriteLine(string.Compare(".exe", ".exe") == 1);  // False
```

Comment: Exactly what was expected and described in the docs? [String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx)  returns 0 for equal, -1 for smaller, 1 for larger. That's how all implementations of [IComparable.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) work.

Comment: You have plenty of answer. If you want to check if they are different, you have to check that the `Compare` returns something different from `0`

Comment: sorry i thought true if equals and false if not. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the MSDN page about [`string.Compare()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx)? It returns a value < 0 if the first string is smaller (in a Lexicographical order) to the second one, a value > 0 if it is greater, 0 if they are equal.

```
doc < exe < txt
```

Note that if you only need to check for equality, then using the `==` operator or the `string.Equals()` is better.

```
bool bDocValue = string.Equals(".doc", ".exe"); // False
bool bDocValue2 = ".doc" == ".exe"; // False
```

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN [String.Compare (String strA, String strB)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) see Return Value section:

- **Less than zero** - strA precedes strB in the sort order.
- **Zero** - strA occurs in the same position as strB in the sort order.
- **Greater than zero** - strA follows strB in the sort order.

Here is the sort order of your extensions strings:

```
.doc
.exe
.txt
```

In your first example `".doc"` precedes `".exe"` and you have *less than zero return value*.

**NOTE** that specification does not say that *greater than zero* is equal to `1`. You should not rely on that value and compare with `== 1`. You should compare with zero instead. Here is different comparisons which you might use

- `result < 0` - check if strA goes before strB in the sort order: `string.Compare(".doc", ".exe")`
- `result == 0` - check if strA equals strB: `string.Compare(".exe", ".exe")`
- `result > 0` - check if strA goes after strB in the sort order: `string.Compare(".txt", ".exe")`

Answer (score 3):

You must compare only with zero:

- Any negative value means that the first string is less

  ```
  .doc
  .exe
   ^______ `d` goes before `e`
  ```
- Zero means that the strings are equal

  ```
  .exe
  .exe
      ^___ strings are equal
  ```
- Any positive value means that the first string is greater

  ```
  .txt
  .exe
   ^______ `t` goes after `e`
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The `.Compare()`does not only check for equality. Check for greater, minor or equal. Is often used for sorting algorythms. Check the interface definition.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx